# I think the two SQL queries are the same but the answeres are different. What is the difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working query:

```
select distinct city
from station
where city not like '[aeiouAEUIO]%[aeiouAEUIO]';
```

Broken Query:

```
select distinct city 
from station
where city like '[^aeiouAEUIO]%[^aeiouAEUIO]';
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include some sample data of cities which are returned in both cases?  i.e. what cities does the second query return that you expect to be excluded?

Comment: you still get an answer from the Broken Query ?

Comment: The queries are totally different.  Please explain why you would think that they should return the same results.

Answer (score 3):

No, these 2 queries are *not* the same. Let's take some very quick sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.station (city varchar(25));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.station
VALUES('London'),
      ('New York'),
      ('Amsterdam'),
      ('Cairo'),
      ('Osaka');
```

Now lets look at the first query's clause: `city NOT LIKE '[aeiouAEUIO]%[aeiouAEUIO]'` This will return rows where the value of `city` does not start with a vowel **and** does not end with a vowel. In the above, that is only one city: Osaka. Running your query will result in the below:

| city |
| --- |
| Amsterdam |
| Cairo |
| London |
| New York |

For the second query, however, the clause is different: `city LIKE '[^aeiouAEUIO]%[^aeiouAEUIO]'`. Here you want rows where neither the first character *or* last character are a vowel. This means that Amsterdam and Cairo are also filtered out as they start and end with a vowel respectively. Giving just:

| city |
| --- |
| London |
| New York |

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. What makes the second query an OR condition while the first is an AND condition? I wrote it thinking that neither the start nor the end would be a vowel

Comment: Because they are completely different. One uses a `LIKE` the other a `NOT LIKE`and one wants to match vowels, and the other wants to match characters that *aren't*. Logically they are simply completely different.

Answer (score -1):

Logically the first expression  is

`not like '[aeiouAEUIO]%[aeiouAEUIO]'` =

`NOT( (starts with [aeiouAEUIO]) AND (ends with [aeiouAEUIO]) )` =

`NOT(starts with [aeiouAEUIO]) OR NOT(ends with [aeiouAEUIO])` =

`(starts with [^aeiouAEUIO]) OR (ends with [^aeiouAEUIO])` =

`city like '[^aeiouAEUIO]%' or city  like '%[^aeiouAEUIO]'`;

So the second query should be

```
select distinct city 
from station
where city like '[^aeiouAEUIO]%' or city like '%[^aeiouAEUIO]'
```

Comment: That is a poor explanation (really, no explanation) and the formatting discourages reading. This does not offer any improvement over the first answer.

Comment: @SMor, added an explanation on which is a real equivalent of the first query. Haven't seen it in the first answer.